# Octopus Deploy Settings Javascript SPA

Tags: octopus-deploy

Can someone very familiar with Octopus Deploy tell me whether it is capable of managing settings for non-dot net applications such as JavaScript SPAs. I'm contemplating introducing a fake web.config with corresponding XML to json conversion as a build step, but don't want to do that if there's some other built in means.

Comment: I discovered after taking in the advice of Sohnee that build steps can have a feature added to allow variables to be substituted in json files; at least in the version of Octopus-Deploy I have. The docs are http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Substitute+Variables+in+Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use tokens like `#{OctopusVariable}` you can get Octopus to substitute the values in any file.

You need to enable this using:

1. Configure Features
2. Substitute variables in files
3. Enter `YourFileName.json` as a Target File

You can also use conditions:

```
#{if MyVar}...#{/if}
```

Comment: This looks promising. You get the green tick if you could link to the online docs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up adding a couple of settings.ENVIRONMENT.js classes to our solution and have Octopus use the right one depending on Octopus.Environment.Name during deployment